# How do I reset Apple's Mail, in Lion, to default settings?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I have been having a bunch of email problems and want to start over.  I have deleted all the IMAP accounts from Mail.  What other files do I need to delete, hidden and otherwise, to make Mail (and only Mail) just like a clean install?

Answer (score 7):

The following directories should be empty:

- `~/Library/Mail`
- `~/Library/Mail Downloads`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Mail`
- `~/Library/Caches/Mail`
- `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.mail`

The following files should be removed:

- `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist*`
- `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.mail.savedState`

Comment: Tried this, but it does not work for me to get of rid of my problem with Mail Default Reader preference selection.

Comment: Then maybe it's better to ask a new question describing your issue. Screenshots may help as well.

Comment: I tried this and now when I open mail after add an account it sits there doing nothing. It doesn't go get my mail from the server.

Comment: The solution was aimed at OS X Lion, things may have changed in the meantime. If deleting the additional file listed in the other answer doesn't solve your problem, it might be better to ask a new question using the Ask Question link at the top. Please add a link/reference to this question here.

Comment: What about **com.apple.mail-shared.plist**, should I remove that one too?

Comment: @rraallvv Move it away and try :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the folders mentioned by Patrix, I discovered that Apple Mail (at least the OS X 10.9 Mavericks version) is using another folder, at:

...../Library/Containers/com.apple.mail

After I had tried to do a clean restart of Mail by disabling (re-naming) all the folders that I thought that it was using (and having done a Force-Quit of the process "cfprefsd" in my username, to further reset caches), my Mail froze on trying to start up.

When I also disabled the folder in Library/Containers, the Mail application was able to start up.

Comment: Which OS X version are you using?